# Using jupyter notebook with an R kernel, how can I suppress printing results updating a data.table by reference?

Tags: r, data.table, output, jupyter-notebook

I'm working in a notebook using data.table, but running some code produces output that I'm not expecting and that does not occur in an R terminal.

This occurs when I update the DT using ':='.

DT = data.table(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
DT[ , b := 6]

Running this cell causes DT to be displayed as output. I saw similar posts about this occurring in knitr, but the answers state that the problem has been fixed, so this would seem to be a different sort of problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can suppress the output using invisible()

```
DT = data.table(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))

invisible(DT[ , b := 6])
```